# Nativescript Drawing Pad - How to get signature with background image?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, signaturepad

Native script Drawing Pad - How to get signed data with the background image?

***View code***

```
<DrawingPad #DrawingPad1
                    height="400"    
                    id="drawingPad" 
                    penColor="#f70202" penWidth="3"  class="draw-pad"  style="background: url('~/images/deer.jpg')no-repeat center ;">
                    </DrawingPad>
```

***angular ts code***

```
let pad = this.DrawingPad1.nativeElement;
  // then get the drawing (Bitmap on Android) of the DrawingPad1
  let drawingImage;
  pad.getDrawing().then(
    (data)=> {
      console.log(data);
      drawingImage = data;
      this.userImage.nativeElement.src = data;
    },(err)=> {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

I need to get data with the background. Pls suggest

Comment: A simple solution could be using the [nativescript-screenshot](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-screenshot) plugin and capture the image of DrawingPad view.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, Thanks for your reply.

Have you tried this? Do we have the option to mention the particular DOM on the page?

Comment: Yes, it does as I mentioned in my previous comment generate image form DrawingPad view.